# How to parse a single line in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse the line number one in the following paragraph using regex.

```
text=" My name is Raj 

and I am an engineer."
```

Can someone help me with the regex to fetch the statement("My name is Raj") from the paragraph

Comment: What exactly do you want to "parse" here? Just find the first linebreak and take the substring.

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for parsing a single line in regex is to match a specific pattern of characters that define the line, followed by a capturing group that captures the contents of the line. For example, if you wanted to parse a line that starts with "Hello," followed by a string of characters, you could create a regex pattern like so:

`/^Hello,(.*)$/`

The `^` character indicates the start of the line and the `$` character indicates the end of the line. The `.*` pattern will match any characters that come after the `Hello,`. Finally, the parentheses around the `.*` create a capturing group which will capture the contents of the line.

Comment: This will in fact match any line, not just the first one. Also, no need for slashes `/` as delimiters for the pattern. Lastly, there's no "Hello," in the input string. So this answer does not really answer anything, does it?

Answer (score 0):

To get the first line:

```
text=''' My name is Raj
and I am an engineer.'''

s=text.split('\n')[0]
print(s)

#Output:
#My name is Raj
```